# Overriding a Javascript property with a function

Tags: javascript

I would like to override an object property with a function, so that whenever the object's property is called, it will invoke the function and return the result.

Surely this should be possible in a dynamic language such as JS?

*Context:*

I'm trying to port some IE-only code to other browsers. The code makes extensive use of the the "Microsoft.XMLDOM" object for parsing and querying XML docs. I'd like to use the standard DOMParser in the non-IE browsers. The problem is that the Microsoft implementation exposes a non-standard 'text' property for XML elements, and this property is used extensively in the code-base, I'd like to tack an equivalent function onto the Element prototype.

```
Element.prototype.text = function() {...}
```

doesn't work since when the code-base does 'myelem.text', it doesn't actually run the function, it just returns a pointer to it.

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Do your target browsers support JS getters and setters?

Comment: Didn't know about those, thanks @AnthonySottile I'll look into it.

Comment: For scalability (later use of the code) you should probably add your own method (or function) which based on the presence, or not, of the `text` property executes a function or just returns the property. That way the handling of the doc will always call the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern enough Javascript (e.g. anything other than IE), [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) can do just that.

```
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'text', {
    'get': function() {
        return this.getText();
    },
    'enumerable': true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need external arguments to the function, you could execute after defining it, like this:

```
Element.prototype.text = (function() {...})();
```

Then, after calling

```
Element.text
```

you will get the returned value from the function.

Comment: This would be a static property that would not necessarily represent the contents of the element if the element was ever changed.